# Why is RingBuffer's getBufferSize() an int but remainingCapacity() is a long?

Tags: java, disruptor-pattern

I am writing some unit test code and need to know that all events published to a disruptor's ring buffer were processed (as said, it's only for a specific test case).

After researching for a couple of hours and not finding any **elegant** solution I decided to use the following code in the test case:

```
while (ringBuffer.getBufferSize() > ringBuffer.remainingCapacity()) {
    Thread.yield();
}
```

It seems to work, but since `getBufferSize()` returns an `int` and `remainingCapacity()` returns a `long` I'm concerned that I'm overlooking something.

Anyone knows why `getBufferSize()` returns an `int` and `remainingCapacity()` returns a `long`? It just doesn't make sense to me, unless it's a bug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note: I don't know why the authors don't cast down to an int. However, I can tell you why it needs to be `long` OR a downcast is needed:

`ringBuffer.remainingCapacity` is a `long` because it is calculated based on the `bufferSize`, subtracting `produced` and adding `consumed`, as seen here in [`MultiProducerSequencer`](https://github.com/LMAX-Exchange/disruptor/blob/master/src/main/java/com/lmax/disruptor/MultiProducerSequencer.java):

```
/**
 * @see Sequencer#remainingCapacity()
 */
@Override
public long remainingCapacity()
{
    long consumed = Util.getMinimumSequence(gatingSequences, cursor.get());
    long produced = cursor.get();
    return getBufferSize() - (produced - consumed);
}
```

`getBufferSize` **is** an `int`. Since both `consumed` and `produced` *are* a `long` (and need to be), this resulting math will also be a `long`.

*This is just my educated guess*, but I assume they don't downcast back to an int for performance reasons, there's no actual harm in returning a `long`, but it's just slightly faster to return the type you have, rather than forcing a cast on users that may not be needed.